# Docker . net6 The configuration file 'AppSettings.json' was not found and is not optional

Tags: docker, .net-6.0

While running the docker command `docker start` I am getting the following error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
The configuration file 'AppSettings.json' was not found and is not 
optional. The expected physical path was '/app/AppSettings.json'.
```

my `.csproj` file:

*Copy Always* property doesn't help:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

my *launchSettings* file:

```
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "copyToOutput": {
      "include": [ "appsettings.json" ]
    },
```

my *docker* file:

I copy all the files, but I still experience the same issue:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -o /app/published-app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine as runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/published-app /app
CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet RealEstateApi.dll
```

I have another docker file that I have tested:

```
COPY RealEstateApi/bin/Release/net6.0/publish/  app/
```

I can see there the: `appsettings.json`
but I get the same issue every time.

Comment: Please note that alpine (and other linux distributions) are case-sensitive for filenames. You copy `appsettings.json` but seem to be loading `AppSettings.json`, which are the same thing in windows but not in the linux filesystem

Comment: yes i know, i have copied it as AppSettings.json.

Comment: But than it was saying that my connection string is null, but when i run it on IIS it's working as it should be

Comment: how you read your appsettings.json file can you share your startup.cs or program.cs file which one reads appsettings.json file

Comment: it's .net 6 so there is no startup, i'm using extension method.
var connectionString = services.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString,
                        new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(0, 0, 0)))
                    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                    .EnableDetailedErrors());

Comment: What does line 15 in Program.cs do?

Comment: builder.Host.UseSerilog();

Comment: because it doesn't see the AppSettings

Comment: when i have changed it to AppSettings in docker.

Comment: it's trying to read the connection string from appsettings but in docker it's AppSettings

Answer (score 2):

[Solved]

```
configuration.AddJsonFile("AppSettings.json") // Duplicate == Json1
  //.AddJsonFile($"AppSettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json") // Duplicate == Json1
  .AddEnvironmentVariables(); // Duplicate == Environment
```

In docker file

```
COPY RealEstateApi/appsettings.json /app/AppSettings.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different approaches to this problem in dotnet core (.NET 6 or .NET 7):

```
var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile($"AppSettings.{environmentName}.json")
    .Build();
```

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

Please be aware the `appsettings.json` file is case sensitive in certain scenarios.